# Restful Authentication Through Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, security, authentication

I am implementing a restful api and I wondering is it possible to securely authenticate using ajax without exposing the authenentication credientials? The credentials that will be used are the same ways that will be passed using curls:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');
```

The will be received using:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
```

Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  This is the exact purpose and use case for implementing [Oauth](http://oauth.net/).

Using Basic `HTTP` Authorization will expose the credentials especially from ajax, because even if you run everything through `HTTPS`, it will still be available in the client code (before any request is made).

**If** you are using this api internally only (not expecting third party developers to utilize it), you might attempt to use a "API Key" instead of the plain text username and password.  This way the key can be regenerated if ever compromised, and never expose your users (likely) reused passwords.

I've found that API key + HTTPS covers a lot of situations like this.

You just generate a unique hash and then use that to authenticate the user... the [Basecamp API](http://developer.37signals.com/basecamp/) uses the API key as the username.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '<API KEY>:x');
```

Comment: So, during the authorization process using ajax, should I just check if the user has a session?

Comment: To get specific help, you need to give specific goals in your question.